# Tutorial on how to import a paper wallet into blockchain.info and send a transaction with message attached then delete it?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, api, paper-wallet

Is there an API call on using the blockchain.info api on how to import a paper wallet and then send a certain amount of funds with a note attached?

Looking for just a sample code of how to do this via the blockchain.info api. Do I need an api key? As I was able to do other functions without an API key it seems.

I have the following api call:

http://127.0.0.1:3000/merchant/7a42f805-3132-4c3f-a6bf-xxxx/new_address?priv=5K1Y8iHsXHzLo4HUhURCdMrdzmrL5nomWKJqqp7cNxxxxx&label=mynewaddress&password=xxxxx

but it doesn't import that private key. It creates a totally new address. The priv setting seems to be ignored. I'm not sure what other api call is there in order to do an import.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a few months since you've asked, but just in case someone else is looking for it. If you have a paper wallet, the easiest thing is to import it into a desktop wallet, and from there you can send your BTC to someone or to an exchange or to another wallet, like the one on blockchain. Some online wallets allow importing the private key but the one on blockchain doesn't seem to - at Least I haven't found a way after looking around.